# My Django custom signup form does not save new users in the Database even after i have tried everything i can

Tags: python, django

So am trying to build a signup page for users on my app but, after I built it, when a user sings up, they are not registered in the database. I used the Django form and also used html and CSS for styling but my custom form does not register user on the database this is the views.py section passing the form after it has been created in the forms.py

```
    def customerRegister(request):
       form = CreateUserForm()
       if request.method == 'POST':
              form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
              if form.is_valid():
                     user = form.save()
                     user.refresh_from_db()
                     user.save()
                     group = Group.objects.get(name = 'Customer')
                     user.groups.add(group)

                     messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)
                     return redirect('login')
       context = {'form': form}
       return render(request,'kumba/register.html', context)
```

forms.py this is my custom form with specific information needed from the user

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({
            'required' : "",
            'name': "username",
            'id' : 'username',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder' : 'Enter Username.....',
            'class' : 'form-input'
        })

        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({
            'required' : "",
            'name': "email",
            'id' : 'email',
            'type': 'email',
            'placeholder' : 'Enter Email.....',
            'class' : 'form-input'
        })

        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({
            'required' : "",
            'name': "password1",
            'id' : 'password1',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder' : 'Enter password.....',
            'class' : 'form-input'
        })

        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({
            'required' : "",
            'name': "password2",
            'id' : 'password2',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder' : 'Confirm password.....',
            'class' : 'form-input'
        })

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

html signup after the form is passed here so that the user sees the fields and input the required information, However, once the user inputs data, they are not saved to the data base. And also as a super user, I can only login from the admin dashboard not from my login form.

```html
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        {{ form.username }}
                        <!--<input type="text" name="username">-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        {{ form.email }}
                        <!--<input type="email" name="email">-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        {{ form.password1 }}
                        <!--<input type="text" name="password1">-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        {{ form.password2 }}
                        <!--<input type="text" name="password2">-->
                    </div>

                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                            <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Register Account">
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

After all this, I have tried to register new users but they are not saved to the database and I can not to figure out what am not doing right. It has kept me stuck for days trying to figure out what the problem is. And all tutorials I see, they show how to make use of the Django signup for not what I really need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use some well tested packages like [django-registration-redux](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that will handle all user registration, login, logout and other needs. Don't waste your time on developing this by yourself. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

**Form action linking to login not customerRegister**

Your form's action is sending the registration information to the login view as opposed to the customerRegister view.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```